# How to change the implementation of getter with Jaxb Xjc?

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb2, xjc

I have the following xsd schema:

```
  <xsd:complexType name="USAddress">
    <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
         <xsd:element name="street" type="xsd:string"/>
         <xsd:element name="city" type="xsd:string"/>
         <xsd:element name="state" type="xsd:string"/>
         <xsd:element name="zip" type="xsd:decimal"/>
     </xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:attribute name="country" type="xsd:NMTOKEN" fixed="US"/>
   </xsd:complexType>
 </xsd:schema>
```

I, using this command to genreate entities for it 
        xjc -p primer.po2 -d src2 po2.xsd
My question is how can i for example add logic in the getter like for example in case of string making lower case to upper case and trim the string.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it just make     JBlock myMethod= method.body();
        myMethod.pos(0);
the pos function will put you at the start of method block